# how to create n items in geometry nodes

Tags: node-editor, geometry

first of all: excuse my very bad english :-D

i made a geometry node of a lego brick, but i stuck at the little pins on the top.

i let create a cylinder at a specific position. but in order of how long and with the brick is - so there must be even more little pins at the other positions.

How can i achive this? have somebody a little tip for me?

some images to show you the problem:
[image: The Node]
[image: The Brick]
[image: The Problem]

EDIT: to clarify my question

i have made a lego brick generator. You can adjust the size of the brick (length and width) is it a 2x1 or a 6x2 Stone etc... I can adjust the size. But the little studs and the number of them on the top is making me some problems. for a 2x1 brick i need two studs, for a 4x4 brick i need 16 studs etc..

the number of studs are a little math, but i need to create and position them for this count - thats the problem of mine.

[image: Brick]

Comment: It is hard to understand exactly what your request is.
Anyway, creating n elements can be achieves using a line with n vertices and then just using the vertex index as the counter.
Please add some more information on your request.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I hope my question is now a little bit easier to understand. :-/ its quit different at another language. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a Grid and Point instances for the cylinders, you can specify the number of the grid dimensions.
See this example in the picture.[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :-D Thats exactly what i need!